# ifelse() to create new factor vector from two other factor vectors fails to return expected value

Tags: r, if-statement

I am using conditional statements and ifelse() to create a new factor with four levels. However, only three of the four levels are correctly returned. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my data:

```
arf <- structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("FORT ERIE", "GRIMSBY", 
"LINCOLN", "NIAGARA-ON-THE-LAKE", "NIAGARA FALLS", "PELHAM", 
"PORT COLBORNE", "ST. CATHARINES", "THOROLD", "WAINFLEET", "WELLAND", 
"WEST LINCOLN"), class = "factor"), Canal = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Canal", 
"No canal"), class = "factor"), QEW = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No QEW", "QEW"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my code:

```
 View(arf)
arf$QEWcanal <- "test"
arf$QEWcanal <- with(arf, 
  ifelse(((Canal == "Canal") & (QEW == "QEW")), "Both",
  ifelse(((Canal == "No canal") & (QEW == "QEW")), "QEW only",
  ifelse(((Canal == "Canal") & (QEW == "No QEW")), "Canal only",
  ifelse(((Canal == "No Canal") & (QEW == "No QEW")), "Neither", "perdition")))))
View(arf)
```

It works for the first three cases, but the last case returns "perdition" instead of "Neither". However, when I replace the last line with `ifelse(((Canal == "No Canal") & (QEW == "No QEW")), "perdition", "Neither")))))`, it works.

This is confusing because `??ifelse` says the useage is `ifelse(test, yes, no)`. However, when I follow *that* useage (i.e., my first block of code above), my last `ifelse()` statement returns "perdition" and not "Neither." Why?

Comment: It's case sensitive, so `No Canal` fails to match with `No canal`

Comment: A couple suggestions, one, it's probably better form to use `dplyr::case_when()` than nesting `ifelse` for this kind of operation. Two, you could use `grepl()` with `ignore.case = TRUE` to match all variations. For example `grepl('No Canal', Canal, ignore.case = TRUE)`. However for your specific example it looks like you can just make `C` lowercase in `No Canal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the fourth condition you code says `No Canal`, but the values in that column say "No canal" (small caps `c` in canal). It works if you adjust that.

Furthermore, I'd recommend not to use `ifelse()` whenever you have more than one condition. `dplyr::case_when()` is much more suitable for these occasions. Here is what that could look like for your code:

```
library(tidyverse)
  
arf |> 
  mutate(QEWcanal = case_when(
    Canal == "Canal" & QEW == "QEW" ~ "Both",
    Canal == "No canal" & QEW == "QEW" ~ "QEW only",
    Canal == "Canal" & QEW == "No QEW" ~ "Canal Only",
    Canal == "No canal" & QEW == "No QEW" ~ "Neither",
    TRUE ~ "peridition"
  ))
#>               Location    Canal    QEW   QEWcanal
#> 1            FORT ERIE No canal    QEW   QEW only
#> 2              GRIMSBY No canal    QEW   QEW only
#> 3              LINCOLN No canal    QEW   QEW only
#> 4        NIAGARA FALLS No canal    QEW   QEW only
#> 5  NIAGARA-ON-THE-LAKE No canal    QEW   QEW only
#> 6               PELHAM No canal No QEW    Neither
#> 7        PORT COLBORNE    Canal No QEW Canal Only
#> 8       ST. CATHARINES    Canal    QEW       Both
#> 9              THOROLD    Canal No QEW Canal Only
#> 10           WAINFLEET No canal No QEW    Neither
#> 11             WELLAND    Canal No QEW Canal Only
#> 12        WEST LINCOLN No canal No QEW    Neither
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't catch this.

Comment: Also, thanks for the dplyr::case_when() solution.